# How do I count the number of times a character "x" is reported in column "ID", and report a weight measure for each row?

Tags: r

```
> head(mini)
   ID        sequence class     
1:   3930271        0  A63B   
2:   3930272        0  A47D     
3:   3930272        1  Y10T 
4:   3930273        0  A61G    
5:   3930273        1  A61G    
6:   3930274        0  B63B
```

I would like to compute the weight of each class to the respective ID. Therefore, I'd need a count of the number of classes per ID and then assign a simple value weight to each class. For example, ID 3930272 has two classes and I would like to have a new column that reports 0.5 as the class weight on ID. 
Visualization here below:

```
   ID        sequence class  weight  
1:   3930271        0  A63B       1
2:   3930272        0  A47D     0.5
3:   3930272        1  Y10T     0.5
4:   3930273        0  A61G     0.5
5:   3930273        1  A61G     0.5
6:   3930274        0  B63B       1
```

Please note that ID 3930273 has two identical classes, but I still want to see a weight of 0.5 for that class. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, sorry I'm a new user and it is not very straightforward to see where you can accept an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `data.table`, here's a quick one-liner:

```r
mini[, weight := 1/.N, by = "ID"]
mini
#         ID sequence class weight
# 1: 3930271        0  A63B    1.0
# 2: 3930272        0  A47D    0.5
# 3: 3930272        1  Y10T    0.5
# 4: 3930273        0  A61G    0.5
# 5: 3930273        1  A61G    0.5
# 6: 3930274        0  B63B    1.0
```

---

Data:

```r
mini <- read.table(header=T, stringsAsFactors=F, text='
   ID        sequence class     
1:   3930271        0  A63B   
2:   3930272        0  A47D     
3:   3930272        1  Y10T 
4:   3930273        0  A61G    
5:   3930273        1  A61G    
6:   3930274        0  B63B   ')
data.table::setDT(mini)
```

Answer (score 2):

With dplyr you'd group by ID and then calculate the weight by dividing 1 by the number of rows of that ID:

```
library(dplyr)
mini = mini %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(weight = 1/n()) %>%
  ungroup()
```